# Create new issue with contents of file from github action

Tags: github-actions

Whenever a commit is pushed that adds a new file named "issues.txt" (in any directory in my repository), I would like it to trigger a github action that will create a new issue with the contents of the new "issues.txt" file as the body.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JasonEtco/create-an-issue](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/create-an-issue) for this purpose. Here is the configuration that works for me:

#### CI configuration:

```yaml
---
name: Test

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - issues.md

jobs:
  create_issue:
    name: Create issue
    timeout-minutes: 5
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:      
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      - uses: JasonEtco/create-an-issue@v2.4.0
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        with:
          filename: issues.md
```

#### issues.md

```
---
title: Someone just pushed
assignees: fabasoad
labels: bug, enhancement
---
Someone just pushed, oh no! Here's who did it: {{ payload.sender.login }}.
```

#### How it looks like:

[image]

> You can rename `issues.md` to `issues.txt` but I suggest you to keep `.md` extension for readability in IDE.

Comment: This is very close to what I need, but I need to use an `issues.md` file in an arbitrary subdirectory. E.g., if the user pushes both "foo/issues.md" and "bar/issues.md", it should create two issues, one with the contents of each "**/issues.md" file. It looks like the trigger can be run on a globbed path (`**/feedback.md`), but the `filename` parameter seems to be hard-coded. Is there any way for that that file can be used as an argument?

Comment: I see. Yeah, this action allows to work with one file only. What can I suggest here is either create own action to do what you need, or do it directly in step using [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) with curl, or create a feature request to _JasonEtco/create-an-issue_ action with this idea, or create pull request to _JasonEtco/create-an-issue_ action with the implementation of this idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own actions and use octokit rest.js to create an issue.
https://github.com/octokit/octokit.js/blob/master/README.md

I think this will help you out if you are using nodejs actions.